# Does point 6 of OSI's definition allow other businesses to sell my app?

Tags: commercial, open-source-definition

https://opensource.org/osd

> **6. No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor**
>
> The license must not restrict anyone from making use of the program in a specific field of endeavor. For example, it may not restrict the program from being used in a business, or from being used for genetic research.

If I author an open-source app and sell it to customers, would point 6 from the *Open Source Definition* allow other businesses to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 6 is pretty much irrelevant, because Point 1 already allows anyone to sell or give away a copy of your app:

> **1. Free Redistribution**
>
> The license shall not restrict any party from selling or giving away
>   the software as a component of an aggregate software distribution
>   containing programs from several different sources. The license shall
>   not require a royalty or other fee for such sale.

Point 6 deals more with not allowing restrictions forbidding use of the app in warfare, commercial products, harming animals, immoral purposes, etc.